# How do you find average of all the even integers from n to n inclusive with while loop? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I am trying to write a program where it calculates the average of a number to a number inclusively. However, when I print the code it prints the average of all the numbers instead of the final result (sum). Is there any way to only print the average of the sum instead of all other numbers?

```
var n = 1;
var sum=0;
var count=0;
 
while (n<=10) {
  sum+=n;
  n+=2;
  count++;
  console.log(""+sum/count);
}
```

Comment: So why are you printing out in the middle of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is simply your console needs to be put under the loop.

Although, using `while` isn't wrong. A `for` loop includes the `step` in the call itself.

```js
var sum = 0;
var count = 0;

for (n = 1; n <= 10; n += 2) {
  sum += n;
  count++;
}

console.log(sum / count);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track maybe you could consider adding some form of input validation:

```js
const convertToInt = (s) => {
    if (isNaN(s)) {
        throw `Parameter: ${s} is not a number!`;
    }
    const x = 1 * s;
    if (!Number.isInteger(x)) {
        throw `Parameter: ${s} is not a integer!`;
    }
    return x;
}

try {
    const start = convertToInt(prompt('Enter the start of the range ', '1'));
    const end = convertToInt(prompt('Enter the end of the range ', '10'));
    
    if (end <= start) {
        throw `Parameter end (${end}) is less or equal to start (${start})!`;
    }
    
    const n = end - start + 1;

    let total = 0;
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        total += i;
    }

    const average = total / n;
    console.log(`The average of the numbers between ${start} and ${end} inclusive is ${average}.`)

} catch (e) {
    console.error(`Error: ${e}`);
}
```